# React Navigation: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Facing issues while using react-navigation navigation.navigate functions.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'navigation.navigate')

```
import React from "react";
import { AccountBackground,  AccountCover,  Title} from "../components/account.styles";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export const AccountScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

setTimeout(() => { navigation.navigate("Login");}, 3000);
return (
        <AccountBackground>
           <AccountCover />
              <Title>Meals To Go</Title>
             <MaterialIcons name="navigate-next" size={48} color="black" />
        </AccountBackground>
  );
};

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { AccountScreen } from "../../features/account/screens/account.screen";
import { LoginScreen } from "../../features/account/screens/login.screen";
import { RegisterScreen } from "../../features/account/screens/register.screen";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const createScreenOptions = { headerShown: false };
export const AccountNavigator = () => {
  return (
     <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={createScreenOptions}>
       <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={AccountScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );};
```

Comment: Please post code, not images of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers.

Comment: Have you tried console log navigation? Are you getting the `navigation` object?

Comment: Rohit. I tried console log navigation and it's undefined. but why? have I missed anything?